# Seperate a label into 2 different Textbox C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, split, textbox

I wanted to know how i could split this label into 2 different textboxes. Before writing here i searched google and came this far, but now both of my textboxes is showing the value 1000. The program is supposed to split the numbers between the x.

**Example:** Left textbox = 80   &   Right textbox = 1000. What am I missing?

```
    private void Split_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = label1.Text;
        // Split string on spaces.
        // ... This will separate all the words.
        string[] words = s.Split('x');
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            Left_txtbox.Text = word;
            Right_Textbox.Text = word;
        }

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add the trim() command in as well because you will end up with a space after the 80 and before the 1000.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = label1.Text;
        string[] words = s.Split('x');
        Left_txtbox.Text = words[0].Trim();
        Right_Textbox.Text = words[1].Trim();
    }
```

or add the split directly into the textbox assign

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = label1.Text;
        Left_txtbox.Text = s.Split('x')[0].Trim();
        Right_Textbox.Text = s.Split('x')[1].Trim();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the loop. You are setting both textboxes with the same value and overwriting it with every iteration so the last values wins.

You could simply assign the values like follows:

```
Left_txtbox.Text = words[0];
Right_Textbox.Text = words[1];
```

Comment: The second variable, here, is the wrong one.  It's trivial, but since the OP uses `word` as a variable, it could be confusing.

Comment: checking array length as adv12 suggested nevertheless is important as well

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead of your `foreach` loop:

```
if (words.Length > 1)
{
    Left_txtbox.Text = words[0];
    Right_Textbox.Text = words[1];
}
```